# Funções Básicas Descritivas

Tags: r

Estou analisando um banco de dados de monitoramento de Unidades de Conservação.

Estou com dificuldades para algumas funções básicas.

Gostaria de saber que funções devo usar para conseguir os seguintes valores com o `R`:

1. Número de entrevistas (`id.entrevista`) por morador (`id.household`)
2. Número médio de entrevistas por morador
3. Número médio de entrevistas por `resex`

Mais de uma linha pode ser referente a mesma `id.entrevista`, por exemplo, a `id.entrevista` 43 tem duas linhas com 43. Este número não é valor, e sim, a identificação da entrevista no banco de dados.

Tentei com a função `aggregate`, mas não obtiver sucesso, já que as minhas variáveis de fatore são `"character"`.

Abaixo segue exemplo do meu banco de dados que contem 1476 linhas

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Poderiam me ajudar, por gentileza, conseguir a função que preciso?

Seguem dados em formato `dput`:

```
set.seed(123)
dados <- data.frame(
  id.entrevista = 1:14, 
  id.household = sample(c("Luiz", "José", "Gelson", "Renan"), 14, TRUE),
  resex = "iriri"
)
```

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Infelizmente, esta pergunta não pode ser reproduzida por quem for tentar respondê-la. Por favor, [dê uma olhada neste link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/824/como-criar-um-exemplo-m%c3%adnimo-reproduz%c3%advel-em-r) e veja como fazer uma pergunta reproduzível em R. Assim, as pessoas que desejarem te ajudar conseguirão fazer isto da melhor maneira possível.

Comment: Pode, por favor, **editar a pergunta** com a saída de `dput(dados)` ou, se a base for muito grande, de `dput(head(dados, 20))`? Nota: `dados` é o nome da base, por exemplo de um data.frame.

Comment: Até reabrirem a pergunta vou deixar aqui comentado. Usando o dplyr as soluções passam por usar [`count()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/tally.html) e depois tirar a média